# How to generate grid points on boundary of $[-1,1]^d$ for arbitrary dimension $d$ and specified resolution?

Tags: lattices, discretization

This must be a trivial thing, but I was not able to find a function for it in *Mathematica*. How do you efficiently create a grid with constant but specific resolution $r$ in all directions on the boundary of $[-1,1]^d$ in arbitrary $d$ dimensions? By that, I mean, for example, for $d=2$ and $r=1/2$ a list with all equidistant points on the edge of the square:

```
points={{-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}
```

[image: 2d plot]

in $d=3$ and $r=1/2$

```
points={
 {-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 0}, 
 {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 1}, {0, -1, -1}, 
 {0, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 1}, {0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, -1}, {0, 1, 0}, 
 {0, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 0, -1}, {1, 0, 0}, 
 {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}
```

[image: 3d plot]

At the moment I am doing this for arbitrary dimension $d$ and specified resolution $r$ with `Table` as follows:

```
d = 3;
r = 1/2;
(*Create indices*)
ids = Array[id, d];
(*Prepare argument for Table*)
arg = {Permutations[ids], {ids[[1]], {-1, 1}}};
Do[
 AppendTo[arg, {ids[[i]], -1, 1, 2*r}]
 , {i, 2, Length@ids}
 ]
arg;
(*Generate points with Table*)
points = Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[Table @@ arg, d];
Length@points
(*Plot in 2D and 3D*)
If[d == 2, Graphics@Point@points]
If[d == 3, Graphics3D@Point@points]
```

but I just wanted to know, if there is already a built-in function or more efficient way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a pretty general solution. This generates the desired boundary lattice points in $[0,1]^d$; apply `Rescale[]` as needed:

```
makeGrid[d_Integer?Positive, n_Integer /; n > 1] := 
    Module[{sh = {{0}, {1}}, ins = ArrayPad[Subdivide[n], -1]},
           Do[sh = Insert[Transpose[Outer[Append, 
              CoordinateBoundsArray[ConstantArray[{0, 1}, k], Into[n]], {0, 1}, k]], 
              Unevaluated[Sequence @@ Flatten[Outer[Append, sh, ins, k], {{2}, {1}}]], 2],
              {k, d - 1}]; sh]
```

Examples:

```
{Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[Flatten[makeGrid[2, 8], 1]]}, Frame -> True], 
 Graphics3D[Sphere[Flatten[makeGrid[3, 5], 2], 0.01], Axes -> True]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: boundary grid points in 2D and 3D]

Comment: Very neat! Learn something new every day.

Comment: I am confused; what is `Into`?

Comment: It's [one of the possible specifications for `CoordinateBoundsArray[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateBoundsArray.html) (fourth usage).

Answer (score 9):

Since version 10.1, there has been a built-in function [`CoordinateBoundsArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateBoundsArray.html) to do this kind of thing. It is readily adapted to your special case.

```
lattice[d_Integer?Positive, r_?NumericQ] :=
  Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray[ConstantArray[{-1, 1}, d], r], d - 1]

lattice[2, 1]
```

> ```
> {{-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, -1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}
> ```

```
lattice[3, 1]
```

> ```
> {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 0}, {-1,0, 1}, 
>  {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 1}, {0, -1, -1}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 1}, 
>  {0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, -1}, {0, 1,0}, {0, 1, 1}, 
>  {1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 0, -1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, 
>  {1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}
> ```

Comment: There is still a need to delete the points within the $r$-hypercube, however.

Comment: @J.M. wrap it in `Select[Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray[ConstantArray[{-1, 1}, d], r], 
  d - 1], Max@Abs@# == 1 &]` as I did - it's worth noting that this is considerably faster than my implementation.

Comment: Presumably there is some sort of optimization going on under the hood.

Comment: @J.M. I should have stated that my answer is only meant to reproduce the `points` output the OP showed.

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like this:

```
generateGrid[dim_] := DeleteCases[Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, dim], {0 ..}]
```

For the case of specifying a resolution as well, try:

```
generateGrid[dim_, r_] := Select[Tuples[Range[-1, 1, r], dim], Max@Abs[#] == 1 &]
Graphics3D@Point@generateGrid[3, 1/2]
```

[image: grid]

But it won't be very efficient for higher dimensions or fine resolution, due to the use of `Tuples[]`, as mentioned in the comments. This alternative might be better in terms of memory than using `Tuples[]`, although it's not any faster:

```
generateGrid2[dim_, r_] := Module[{coords, pt},
  coords = Range[-1, 1, r];
  Last@Reap@Do[
     pt = coords[[1 + IntegerDigits[i, Length@coords, dim]]];
     If[Max@Abs[pt] == 1, Sow[pt]], 
    {i, (Length@coords)^dim}]
  ]
```

You could always compile this to make it even faster, but of course the algorithm complexity remains the same:

```
generateGridCompile = Compile[{{dim, _Integer}, {r, _Real}},
   Module[{coords, pt, pts, len, i, n = 1},
    coords = Range[-1, 1, r];
    len = Length@coords;
    pts = Table[0., {i, len^dim - 1}, {j, dim}];
    Do[pt = coords[[1 + IntegerDigits[i, len, dim]]];
     If[Max[Abs[pt]] == 1, pts[[n]] = pt; n++];,
     {i, len^dim}];
    pts],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

[image: performance plot]

Comment: ...or `DeleteCases[Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, 3], {0 ..}]`.

Comment: For finer grids and larger dimensions I would expect this to slow down as `Tuples` will be making many more elements than are required. Is this likely to be the case? I'd be interested to find a more efficient alternative. (Although I do admit `Tuples` was my first port of call!)

Comment: Thanks. But what about the resolution to be specified? But I think this is my fault, I should have been more specific, sorry :D

Comment: @MauricioLobos I've added that, but as I mention you may run into problems with high dimensions or fine resolutions.