# Unexpected behavior from CoordinateBoundingBoxArray with Into[1] and 0.41

Tags: functions, numerics, machine-precision

I want to get the four corners of a Cuboid. This usually works:

```
CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{-{1., 1.}, {1., 1.}}, Into@1]
```

gives

```
{{{-1., -1.}, {-1., 1.}}, {{1., -1.}, {1., 1.}}}
```

as expected.

The expressions `CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{-{1., 0.40}, {1., 0.40}}, Into@1]` and `CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{-{1., 0.42}, {1., 0.42}}, Into@1]` evaluate to a 2x2 matrix of 2d coordinates as well, as I would expect. But for some reason

```
CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{-{1., 0.41}, {1., 0.41}}, Into@1]
```

gives

```
{{{-1., -0.41}}, {{1., -0.41}}}
```

I am confident that this is not the way this should work.

Comment: If you're confident, the thing I do is to report it to WRI, not to Mma.SE.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Done. I was expecting maybe someone would know a reason for this.

Comment: The problem is that `1/0.82*0.82` is less than `1`.

Comment: Due to Michael's comment: `CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{-{1, 41/100}, {1, 41/100}}, Into@1]`; see also the output of `SetAccuracy[1/0.82*0.82, 20]`.

Comment: I am feeling quite ignorant right now; what is `Into`?

Comment: `CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{min,max},Into[n]]`
divides into n equal steps in each dimension. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateBoundingBoxArray.html

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. See [CoordinateBoundsArray](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateBoundsArray.html). It is otherwise undocumented AFAIK

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's a decorator to give an argument another meaning, like e.g. `Key` (which, however, has documentation on its own, while `Into` does not, as has been pointed out).

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, [you've asked that before](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115991/121660#comment330704_121660)... ;)

Comment: @J.M. At this point my early senility isn't even an open secret, it's just plain out in the open.  I'll keep plugging away until I forget how to sign in or what `@@` does.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: She wears coats of many colors: sings country music, used to have her own TV entertainment series, runs a huge amusement park in Tennessee, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem arises from rounding in machine precision.  For instance the second-coordinate interval `{-0.41, 0.41}` leads to this edge case, a one ulp error:

```
SetAccuracy[1/0.82*0.82, Infinity]
(*  9007199254740991/9007199254740992  *)
```

It turns out this affects how the range is computed, because `Floor` is used on it and it returns `0` instead of `1`.

One workaround is to avoid machine precision, using either exact numbers or arbitrary precision.
Another workaround is to create a `Floor` that applies a machine-precision fudge factor, in the way that `Equal` has the fudge factor `` Internal`$EqualTolerance ``.

First way:

```
ClearAll[cbba];
cbba = SetPrecision[
    CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[
     # /. x_?Developer`MachineRealQ :> SetPrecision[x, $MachinePrecision], ##2],
     Precision[#]] &;
```

Second way, mostly just as evidence that `Floor` is implicated:

```
ClearAll[cbba];
cbba[v_, rest__] /; Precision[v] === MachinePrecision :=
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{Floor},
   Unprotect@Floor;
   Floor[x_] /; ! TrueQ[$in] := Block[{$in = True},   (* Villegas-Gayley *)
     Floor[x + 10^Internal`$EqualTolerance $MachineEpsilon Abs[x]]];
   Protect@Floor;
   CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[v, rest]
   ];
```

Or even more simply:

```
ClearAll[cbba];
cbba[args___] /; FreeQ[{args}, Floor] :=
  Block[{Floor = Round},
   CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[args]
   ];
```

I can't find a way in which this substitution of `Round` for `Floor` causes a problem in `CoordinateBoundingBoxArray`, but I suppose it might.

Test:

```
cbba[{-{1., 0.41}, {1., 0.41}}, Into@1]
(*  {{{-1., -0.41}, {-1., 0.41}}, {{1., -0.41}, {1., 0.41}}}  *)
```

Comment: Awesome research here, thank you!