# Generating a grid such that the elements in each row add up to one

Tags: lattices, discretization

I'd like to generate a grid such that each element is a dimension $d$ vector ($\vec v$) of non negative components that add up to one. I could use the approach in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115991/how-to-generate-grid-points-on-boundary-of-1-1d-for-arbitrary-dimension-d) and then choose among the resulting grid the points satisfying the constraint that $\vec v.\vec \iota=1,$ but I think it wouldn't be
too efficient (as most points won't satisfy the constraint).

Currently, for $d=3$, I make do with nested `Do` as in

```
step = .5
Do[
 Print[Chop[{i, j, 1 - i - j}]];
 , {i, 0, 1, step}, {j, 0, 1 - i, step}]
```

but this requieres me to add additional indexes if I want a larger $d$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `IntegerPartitions`, which (despite its name) also partitions rationals. Your problem is to partition the number 1 into a set of $d$ nonnegative integer multiples of `step`:

```
d = 3;
step = 1/2;
Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[1, {d}, Range[0, 1, step]], 1]
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1/2, 1/2, 0}, {1/2, 0, 1/2}, {0, 1/2, 1/2}} *)
```

`Permutations` makes sure that you get all possible partitions in all $d$ dimensions. You may want to use `Sort` on the result, depending on use case.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for something like this.

```
myGrid[d_, n_] := (#/Total[#] & /@ RandomReal[1., {n, d}])
```

This should work for number of rows, `n`, each having `d` elements. Let's look at a couple of examples.

```
SeedRandom[1]; g1 = myGrid[3, 2]
```

> `{{0.475687, 0.0648416, 0.459471}, {0.379475, 0.487694, 0.132832}}`

```
Total /@ g1
```

> `{1., 1.}`

```
SeedRandom[1]; g2 = myGrid[5, 5]
```

> ```
>  {{0.380624, 0.0518834, 0.367649, 0.087452, 0.112392}, 
>   {0.0339626, 0.280141, 0.119421, 0.204589, 0.361886}, 
>   {0.0812216, 0.287062, 0.162136, 0.0948983, 0.374682}, 
>   {0.291637, 0.32702, 0.204302, 0.103509, 0.0735315}, 
>   {0.274026, 0.0608128, 0.144656, 0.336122, 0.184383}}
> ```

```
Total /@ g2
```

> `{1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}`

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to construct full grid rather than some random elements of it.